# Where on the backbone does a peptide get protonated at low pH?

Tags: acid-base, ph, proteins, amino-acids

As a particular example, how does the backbone of a peptide look at $\mathrm{pH}~2$?  Where does the backbone get protonated in such an acidic solution?

I know that at low $\mathrm{pH}$ the free amino acids have $\ce{-NH3+}$ and $\ce{-COOH}$ groups, but when the residues are linked together into peptide bonds, where do the extra protons go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the backbone of a polypeptide, you would find amide bonds formed from the amino (NH<sub>2</sub>) and carboxyl (COOH) groups of two amino acids. Water is lost in this condensation process:

[image: Condensation of two amino acids/peptides]

The peptide backbone is considered to simply be the repeating C<sup>α</sup>–C–N units. In the peptide shown below (a hexapeptide), the backbone is bolded. The side chains of each amino acid residue (R<sup>1</sup>, R<sup>2</sup>, ...) are not part of this backbone.

[image: Hexapeptide backbone]

Amides are only very weakly acidic and very weakly basic, and do not undergo appreciable protonation *or* deprotonation under aqueous conditions.

Therefore, you only consider the terminal amino and carboxyl groups. So, at pH 2, both the N- and C-termini will be protonated:

[image: Hexapeptide at pH 2]

Of course, if any of your residues contain a group that could become protonated, you need to consider its p*K*<sub>a</sub> as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to visualize the question on your own using the [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/) molecule editor.

*I'm not adding screenshots from my own computer since I run Avogadro with a localized German menu.*

1. **Generate some tripeptides**
   From the menu chose **Build --> Insert --> Insert peptide**
   Chose three amino acids. Knowing the three-letters codes is an advantage ;-)
   You might want to try this with amino acids that contain additional $\ce{-NH2}$ groups, such as *Lys* and those having additional $\ce{-COOH}$, such as *Glu*.
2. **Adjust structure for pH**
   From the menu chose **Build --> Add Hydrogens for pH...**
   Select a pH of 2 and have a look for changes.